# ¿Cómo agregar corchetes, paréntesis y llaves en una expresión regular?

Tags: regex

Esta es la expresión regular que estoy usando, solo permite mayúsculas y números,pero quiero agregar que acepte paréntesis, corchetes y llaves {}.

```
regEx="/[A-Z0-9\s]/i"
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: Saco el flag i debido al comentario de @AnaMuñoz

Deberías agregar un escape al caracter para poder aceptarlo.

Por lo tanto debería ser así:

```
regEx="/[A-Z0-9\s\{\}\(\)]/"
```

Y así con cualquier caracter especial que quieras utilizar y sea reservado de regex.

Comment: Gracias. Lo he puesto así, pero ahora ya no respeta mayúsculas.

Comment: Perfecto. Las mayúsculas no las está respetando por el flag "i" que signfica "ignore case". Si necesitas que respete las mayúsculas sólo basta con sacar el "i". Edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono :D